# Produce balanced mini batch with Dataset API

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I've a question about the new dataset API (tensorflow 1.4rc1).
I've a unbalanced dataset wrt to labels `0` and `1`. My goal is to create balanced mini batches during the preprocessing.

Assume I've two filtered datasets:

```
ds_pos = dataset.filter(lambda l, x, y, z: tf.reshape(tf.equal(l, 1), []))
ds_neg = dataset.filter(lambda l, x, y, z: tf.reshape(tf.equal(l, 0), [])).repeat()
```

Is there a way to combine these two datasets such that the resulting dataset looks like `ds = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]`:

Something like this:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((ds_pos, ds_neg))
dataset = dataset.apply(...)
# dataset looks like [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, ...]
dataset = dataset.batch(20)
```

My current approach is:

```
def _concat(x, y):
   return tf.cond(tf.random_uniform(()) > 0.5, lambda: x, lambda: y)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((ds_pos, ds_neg))
dataset = dataset.map(_concat)
```

But I've the feeling there is a more elegant way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using tensorflow dataset with stratified sampling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53505150/using-tensorflow-dataset-with-stratified-sampling)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are on the right track. The following example uses `Dataset.flat_map()` to turn each pair of a positive example and a negative example into two consecutive examples in the result:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((ds_pos, ds_neg))

# Each input element will be converted into a two-element `Dataset` using
# `Dataset.from_tensors()` and `Dataset.concatenate()`, then `Dataset.flat_map()`
# will flatten the resulting `Dataset`s into a single `Dataset`.
dataset = dataset.flat_map(
    lambda ex_pos, ex_neg: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(ex_pos).concatenate(
        tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(ex_neg)))

dataset = dataset.batch(20)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I can remove the sampling step for each data point :)

Comment: I wanted to use the same approach for a multi-class classification problem. However, it is painfully slow. Is there a more effective way of producing balanced mini batches in a non-binary classification task?

Comment: @aseipel One option would be to divide your examples into one file per class, then use `Dataset.range(NUM_CLASSES).interleave(dataset_for_class, cycle_length=NUM_CLASSES)` (where `dataset_for_class(c)` is a function that loads that file for class `c`).

Comment: @aseipel -- Do you know what part is slow in the multi-class case? Usually reinitializing iterators is very slow so I would think that the `zip` and `flat_map` solution would be better than having an iterator for each class.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind regarding this solution is that `zip` will create a dataset with size equal to the smallest one that is being zipped. I think this is why the OP used `repeat` on `ds_neg`. I assume this was to make sure all of the majority class' data, `ds_pos`, would be used.

Comment: @mrry could you utilize `interleave` to produce intentionally imbalanced batches? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57331048/tensorflow-1-14-make-intentionally-unbalanced-mini-batch-with-dataset-api